# jQuery Tab Disabling Syntax variations

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why am I finding that using:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", 2); // API version - doesn't work
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [2]);  // this works
```

Using the second line may be the reason for odd behavior on the page.  That is described in a previous question I posted that has not been resolved.

Comment: Why doesn't the first script work?
The answer may help me figure out why the second script only works some of the time.  This is in reference to my older question at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443311/trouble-disabling-jquery-ui-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation ([options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-disabled) and [method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-disable)), when you use options, it only takes an array. But if when you use the `disable` method, you can use either an array or an integer. So, if you want to disable the tab with index 2, you can do any one of the following:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [2]);
```

OR

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs("disable", 2);
```

OR

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs("disable", [2]);
```